# How can I get an xterm to display on Parallels VM running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, xorg, x11-forwarding

I'd like to bring up a simple X application on my Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop running in a Parallels VM, and though I can get all X applications and servers to play nicely together in  my network of VM's, the OS X xterm displayed on the Ubuntu VM X server is proving problematic as follows:

I have a VM running Ubuntu 12.04 in Parallels Desktop 8 for Mac, which is running Mavericks 10.9.1 and XQuartz 2.7.5

I can bring up an xterm on the OSX host X server's twm from Ubuntu VM just fine with

```
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ xterm -display 192.168.0.2:0
```

I can ssh just fine into Ubuntu VM (10.211.55.8) from host laptop (192.168.0.2)

```
ssh parallels@10.211.55.8
```

When an xterm is run from OSX to be displayed on the linux VM, an error results - I've done an `xhost +` on the linux VM - that doesn't help.  The error is simple, yet not easy to make go away - I've read many different threads on our site, and elsewhere - nothing has worked for me:

```
xterm -display 10.211.55.8:0
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 10.211.55.8:0
```

I've even tried using the old `ssh -X parallels@10.211.55.8` approach, and cannot get that to work, either - here are those errors - doing this command also seems to mess up which server thinks it's 192.168.0.2, but that's a different issues...:

```
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ ssh -X parallels@10.211.55.8
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-53-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

217 packages can be updated.
92 updates are security updates.
```

*Note to self - time to update some packages in the Ubuntu VM...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial solution to this problem that works:

On the OS X Mavericks XQuartz side, change /etc/sshd_config parameters as follows

```
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:/etc$ egrep '^(X11Forwarding|X11UseLocalhost)' /etc/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
```

On the Ubuntu Linux 12.04 Parallels VM side, change /etc/ssh/sshd_config parameters as follows

```
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ egrep '^(X11Forwarding|X11UseLocalhost)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost no
```

Then, from the Ubuntu Linux 12.04 Parallels VM, open a Terminal, and ssh into the Mavericks OSX server with the X11 forwarding option, -X, and kick off the desired X applications(s):

```
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:/etc/ssh$ ssh -X whmcclos@192.168.0.2
Last login: Mon Jan 13 19:07:22 2014 from 192.168.0.72
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ xemacs &
[1] 7088
```

Here's a picture demonstrating that this method works

[image: Show X application displayed back to Parallels VM running Ubuntu 12.04]

Unfortunately, this doesn't make the way we used to accomplish this task work as it once did i.e. we used to do something like this - Is this still possible?

```
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ ssh whmcclos@mbp
Last login: Mon Jan 13 19:47:31 2014 from 192.168.0.72
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ export DISPLAY=192.168.0.72:0
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 192.168.0.72:0
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$
```

The thing that is interesting is that when I ssh with the -X switch, the DISPLAY environment variable gets set to something I would have never guessed - something to think about:

```
parallels@parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform:~$ ssh -X whmcclos@mbp
Last login: Mon Jan 13 19:48:12 2014 from 192.168.0.72
whmcclos@Williams-MacBook-Pro:~$ echo $DISPLAY
Williams-MacBook-Pro.local:10.0
```